# How to make child values inside map function editable via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to make the mapping child values input editable via props?
I have this simple accordion in my Next.js App which I'd like to reuse with different inputs and what I am naming `listItemTitle` can vary from input to input. This can either be something like `item.question[0].questionTitle` or `item.partner[0].partnerLastName`.

How do I make this as scalable as possible?

E.g.

```
// Child Component

const SimpleAccordion = ({ listItems, listItemTitle }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      {
        listItems && listItems.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={ index }>
            { listItemTitle } // Make this editable via props
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </section>
  )
}

// Parent Component
...
<SimpleAccordion
  listItems={ pageData.questionSelector }
  listItemTitle={ question[0].questionTitle }
/>
...
```

Comment: I don't understand your question but from what im picking you want the children to be editable? then I suggest you don't use a list iem and use an input or you can give the list item the editable html attribute. I think you need to use the state in this scenario if you want your data to not be static

Comment: Thank you @AyabongaQwabi, what I meant with "editable" was I want the props to be editable, not something like a "text field". I was considering the solution MarcSanchez suggested below but thought there might be something more "scalable" without creating components for every child. Whatever, I went with the proposed and upvoted solution.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you want to make SimpleAccordion generic, in that case you can pass the component to use to that function.

```
// Parent Component
...
import QuestionListItem from './QuestionListItem'
...
<SimpleAccordion
  listItems={ pageData.questionSelector }
  listItemComponent={QuestionListItem}/>
...
or     
...
import PartnerListItem from './PartnerListItem'
...    
<SimpleAccordion
  listItems={ pageData.questionSelector} 
  listItemComponent={PartnerListItem}/>
```

This will be the generic SimpleAccordion :

```
// Generic component
const SimpleAccordion = ({ listItems, listItemComponent }) => {
  let Component = listItemComponent
  return (
    <section>
      {
        listItems && listItems.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={ index }>
            <Component item={item}/>
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </section>
  )
}
```

You can declare as many list items as you want, for example:

```
const QuestionListItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <span>{item.question[0].questionTitle}</span>
  )
}

const PartnerListItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <span>{item.partner[0].partnerLastName}</span>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcSanchez, yeah you understood it correctly. I have thought of your way but wondered if there is anything that replaces some data input only.

Whatever, it's nothing too complicated for my App, so that's fine then...

Thanks, will upvote